# How to print defaultdict variable without its type?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

In the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

confusion_proba_dict = defaultdict(float)

for i in xrange(10):
    confusion_proba_dict[i] = i + 10

print confusion_proba_dict
```

Output is:

```
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15, 6: 16, 7: 17, 8: 18, 9: 19})
```

But, I need output to be:

```
{0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15, 6: 16, 7: 17, 8: 18, 9: 19}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you need the output to be that? You could just call `dict` on your defaultdict result `confusion_proba_dict` to get what you want: `dict(confusion_proba_dict)`. But I still think that is excessive and not necessary.

Comment: You're not taking any advantage of the `defaultdict` class in your code. In fact the values in `confusion_proba_dict` will end up being integer values after the `for` loop executes since the `float` factory function is never invoked. Just create a regular dictionary using `confusion_proba_dict = {i: float(i) + 10 for i in range(10)}`. The result will be `{0: 10.0, 1: 11.0, 2: 12.0, 3: 13.0, 4: 14.0, 5: 15.0, 6: 16.0, 7: 17.0, 8: 18.0, 9: 19.0}` and it will make the whole issue about printing `defaultdict`s disappear.

Comment: @martineau if you do it like that, you don't need to the explicit call to float, `{i: i + 10.0 for i in range(10)}` work the same with the implicit type conversion

Answer (score 29, accepted):

just transform it to a regular dict

```
print( dict(confusion_proba_dict) )
```

but if you are going to use like that, just use a regular dict as you don't use any of the advantages of defaultdict

Comment: Actually, it's not necessary to convert the `defaultdict` instance to a `dict` first. Instead just call the base class `dict`'s method for getting the string representation, but pass it the derived class instance as its `self` argument. i.e. `print( dict.__repr__(confusion_proba_dict) )`. Avoiding the conversion will be slightly more efficient, more so obviously for larger dictionaries. This is essentially what @idjaw was suggesting.

Comment: @martineau that is interesting, but kind of hacky. About the other point, well the same can be said about Waxrat, the difference is that I explicitly suggest to use a regular dict instead, therefore mine was the accepted answer, I think...

Comment: Copperfield: If the hackiness bothers you, the same thing can be done more formally by deriving a subclass of `defaultdict` whose `__repr__()` method did essentially the same thing. That approach would take a few additional lines of code, of course, but either way, would avoid the overhead of having to convert the instance temporarily into a regular dictionary.

Comment: What if `confusion_proba_dict` is a nested collection where internally it has `defaultdict`? How would you convert the nested items?

Comment: @Ari in that case is probably better to do a martineau said a make a subclass of defaultdict that print how you want and use that instead

Answer (score 9):

Funny solution ! ( works also if you have defaultdict of defaultdict ! )

```
import json
import pprint
pprint.pprint(json.loads(json.dumps(confusion_proba_dict)))
```

Comment: This is actually a great solution for a nested defaultdict of defaultdict.

Answer (score 6):

Python 2:

```
print dict(confusion_proba_dict)
```

Python 3:

```
print(dict(confusion_proba_dict))
```

Comment: Note for Python 3 users who might come across this question and look at the answer. You need to wrap with parentheses: `print(dict(confusion_proba_dict))`, since `print` is no longer a statement in Python 3.