# Python dictionary with a tuple and tuple count as the value

Tags: python, tuples, defaultdict

I have a `.csv` file:
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arGff.png)
containing packet header data from a wireshark scan that I am iterating through line by line with a for loop. The list contains around 100,000 items, many of which are repeated. I am trying to find how many times each destination IP address is accessed using TCP protocol(6) on each port ranging from 1 to 1024. Essentially I am trying to create something that looks like this:

```
{ip address: {(protocol:port):count}}
```

Where I will know how many times a combination of protocol/port tried to use the IP address as a destination. So far I've tried this:

```
dst = defaultdict(list)
for pkt in csvfile:
   if(pkt.tcpdport > 0 and pkt.tcpdport < 1025):
       tup = (pkt.proto, pkt.tcpdport)
       dst[pkt.ipdst].append(tup)
```

When I try to print this out I get a list of IP addresses with the protocol, port tuple listed multiple times per IP address. How can I get it so that I show the tuple followed by a count of how many times it occurs in each dictionary entry instead?

Comment: Define `dst` as `dst = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))`, and use: `dst[pkt.ipdst][tup] += 1`.

Comment: @mcoav Thanks! That seems to do the trick, but now it prints out `[('199.222.69.4', defaultdict(<type 'int>, {(6,25): 15}))` Is there a way to get rid of `defaultdict(<type 'int>` and just display the numbers?

Comment: @KyleWollman Try changing it to `defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(dict))` ?

Comment: @Adi219 thanks for the feedback. Doing that tells me that you can't use += with type dict, but instead I'm iterating through dst and doing `print i, dict.__repr__(dst[i])` as suggested here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316224/how-to-print-defaultdict-variable-without-its-type) which works.

Comment: @KyleWollman Yeah that approach seems better! As I say below, I've just heard about `defaultdict` so any of my advice on it may be wrong! (my comment above was a complete guess!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the line `dst[pkt.ipdst].append(tup)` is telling `python`, get the value associated with the IP address, and then append the tuple to it. In this case, that means you're appending the tuple to the dictionary associated with the IP address. This is why you're seeing multiple tuples listed per IP address.

To fix this, simply change your line to `dst[pkt.ipdst][tup] += 1`. This is telling `python` to get the dictionary associated with the IP address, get the count associated with the tuple in that dictionary, and then add 1. When printed, this should appear as intended.

Also, define `dst` as `defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(dict))`  so that in case the protocol,port combination hasn't been tried, it won't throw a `KeyError`.